# Current Joomla Beta Stats

Tags: discussion

The JSE Beta has decreased in activity a little over the last week or 2. The current stats are as follows: (live Area 51 stats can be found [here](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/58842/joomla))

[image]

- Questions per day is a little off and could be improved. I will be starting to add questions myself as I haven't done so yet and I would also like to encourage other that don't usually to do the same too. Even if it turns into a wiki, the more the better.
- Percentage of answered questions is brill so no comment on that.
- The site is current a third through the beta phase but I have a good feeling the reputation targets will be rached.
- Answer ratio should be at the "Excellent" stage. Even if you see an answer that already has a few upvotes, please share you own as well. I remember when the site was first launched, each question was generating a good 3-4 answers.
- Problem with this is, the site is still very new. I've been flagging a few questions on Stackoverflow to be migrated over to JSE. Some have worked but a few have been declined. But the more questions we get migrated over here, the better.

Comment: agreed... it needs some work to keep it going... I will also try to ask questions and add a few extra answers on some questions. And the wiki part is essential and we should try to set it up, so everything joomla related to have a good reference in this site.

Answer (score 2):

Here are the stats after 150 days. The big difference is the increase traffic.

[image]

Comment: Indeed the traffic is increasing which is brilliant. I think in 2-3 months we will be getting 1.5k visits per day. The one main thing that needs doing is more answers need to be written for questions. Even if an answer that already exists has a few votes and is accepted, other answers should be written as there could sometimes be an alternative

Answer (score 1):

There is a good thread on the g+ on suggestions we have shared too

https://plus.google.com/+GaryBarclay/posts/LXhMRMVPftd